# 1.9.0.1 how to solve The password cannot be empty.problem?

Tags: customer, registration

I continue to search for the solution of this problem in magento 1.9.0.1 nothing have worked for me,.please help

Comment: When you are getting this issue? Can you provide more explanation to your question?

Comment: Hi Gorai, thank for your interest, so in magento 1.9.0.1 this problem is really hard to solve, i have tried all the solution online but seems nothing work for me the customers when they try to create an account they have the always problem : "The password cannot be empty."  the rest fortunatly work fine,..

Comment: So, the customer login work perfectly, only the register do not work and reload with the same problem, >password don't match, i have tried to look into the login.phtml to do the same in register but seem perfectly the same